# Query SQL Server From Specific Time On Previous Date To Specific Time On Current Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date-arithmetic

Sorry for the noob SQL question.  I have a table in SQL with a DateTime column.  I need to run a script daily to show any lines from 8am yesterday until 8am today.  So for example, today I would run:

```
select *
from Table
Where DateTime > '2020-12-30 08:00:00.000' and DateTime < '2020-12-31 08:00:00.000'
```

I also know that I could run this, but this will only give me the previous day through the current time:

```
select *
from Table
Where DateTime >= DATEADD(day,-1, GETDATE()) and DateTime < GETDATE())
```

But is there a trick to creating the script so I can get 8am yesterday through 8am today without manually editing the script every day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
select *
from mytable
where 
    datetime >= dateadd(hour, 8, dateadd(day, -1, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate()))))
    and datetime < dateadd(hour, 8, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate()))))
```

Comment: That one at least doesn't throw an error...  But it doesn't return any of the results.

Edit:  the first 1 needed to be a -1.  I think that gave me exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherCass: I just fixed a problem in the arithmetics. It should work as required now.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `getdate()` to a `date` and back to `datetime` to truncate it to today 00:00:00. Then use `dateadd()` but with hours. -16 for yesterday 08:00:00, +8 for today 08:00.

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat
       WHERE nmuloc >= dateadd(hour, -16, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())))
             AND nmuloc < dateadd(hour, 8, convert(datetime, convert(date, getdate())));
```